# How should I evaluate the numerical integral of a function with divergent part substracted?

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to evaluate the following integral numerically in Mathematica, 
$$\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{1}{(1 - e^t)^{10}} - (\frac{1}{t^{10}} - \frac{5}{t^9} + \frac{145}{12 t^8} - \frac{75}{
 4 t^7} + \frac{3013}{144 t^6} - \frac{285}{16 t^5} + \frac{4523}{378 t^4} - \frac{6515}{
 1008 t^3} + \frac{7129}{2520 t^2} - \frac{1}{t}))dt$$
which is convergent since the part that is subtracted from $\frac{1}{(1-e^x)^{10}}$ is essentially the negative powers of the Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-e^x)^{10}}$ near 0, which is the divergent part.

However, if I directly use NIntegrate in Mathematica, I get a divergent result. This is not too surprising given the unrealistic plot of the integrand near zero:

[image: The plot of the integrand given by Mathematica]

So is there a good way to actually evaluate this numerical integral?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please write your expressions in Mathematica format.

Comment: FYI, the oscillation near 0 (caused by rounding error) may not be your only problem;  Mathematica complains about slow convergence of the integral even if you integrate from 1 to ∞.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your integral effectively diverges.
Let's define:

```
ee[x_] := 1/(1 -E^x)^10
(*div is the divergent part*)
div[x_] := Evaluate[Series[ee[x], {x, 0, -1}] // Normal]
all[x_] := ee[x] - div[x]
```

You're right that you "killed" the divergence at zero:

```
Integrate[all[x], {x, 0, 1}] // N
(* 0.253202 *)
```

But the "original" function's integral was already converging in {1,  Infinity}

```
Integrate[ee[x], {x, 1, Infinity}] // N
(* 0.0002918 *)
```

While the "new" added part integral diverges in this interval:

```
Integrate[div[x], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of div[x] does not converge on {1,[Infinity]}. >>

so the whole thing won't converge

As your integral from `1` onwards has a closed (but longish)  form, if you want a peep at the divergence form you may evaluate

```
k = Integrate[all[x], {x, 1, p}, Assumptions -> Element[p, Reals]];
Plot[k, {p, 1, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
s = k /. p -> 1/u;
Plot[s, {u, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 10}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My intention is how to deal with integrals with their divergence part subtracted. I chose a bad example here since the Laurent expansion contains 1/t term which is divergent. However, even if I evaluate the integral from 0 to 1, say Integrate[
 1/(1 - Exp[t])^10 - (1/t^10 - 5/t^9 + 145/(12 t^8) - 75/(4 t^7) + 
    3013/(144 t^6) - 285/(16 t^5) + 4523/(378 t^4) - 6515/(
    1008 t^3) + 7129/(2520 t^2) - 1/t), {t, 0, 1}], Mathematica still tells me it is divergent.

Comment: But div[x_] := Evaluate[Series[ee[x], {x, 0, -1}] // Normal] works well. Would you like to elaborate on why it is the case?

Comment: @user110373 take a look at `Series[ee[x], {x, 0, -1}] // Normal` ... it lacks the `Exp[ ]` part ...

Comment: You mean the O[x^0] part? But why doesn't it converge if I explicitly subtract the result of Series[ee[x], {x, 0, -1}] // Normal from  1/(1 - Exp[t])^10 and do the integral?

Comment: @user110373 I don't know how the old version behave but v10.3 gives finite answer of your expression. This question may be due to the bad regulator. I'll post a answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think Taylor expansion is a bad regulator to regulate the divergent part of the integration. The following method is meant to give you a feel of the behavior instead of a concrete solution.

First, rewrite your integration to
$$\int_0^\infty dt\, \frac{1}{(1-e^{t+i \epsilon})^{10}}.$$
we will set $\epsilon\to 0$ at last step to see how it behave.

The above integration can be easily done by

```
Integrate[1/(1 - E^(t + I \[Epsilon]))^10, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0]
```

you will get:

> $$\frac{num1}{2520 \left(-1+e^{i \epsilon }\right)^9}+\log \left(1-e^{-i \epsilon }\right)$$
>   $$num1:=-41481 e^{i \epsilon }+120564 e^{2 i \epsilon }-210756 e^{3 i \epsilon }+236754 e^{4 i \epsilon }-173250 e^{5 i \epsilon }+80220 e^{6 i \epsilon }-21420 e^{7 i \epsilon }+2520 e^{8 i \epsilon }+7129$$

the $num1\to 280$ when $\epsilon \to 0$, so Taylor expansion it

```
Series[280/(2520 (-1 + E^(I \[Epsilon]))^9) + Log[1 - E^(-I \[Epsilon])], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]
```

gives you:

> $-\frac{i}{9 \epsilon ^9}-\frac{1}{2 \epsilon ^8}+\frac{13 i}{12 \epsilon ^7}+\frac{3}{2 \epsilon ^6}-\frac{1069 i}{720 \epsilon ^5}-\frac{89}{80 \epsilon ^4}+\frac{29531 i}{45360 \epsilon ^3}+\frac{761}{2520 \epsilon ^2}-\frac{i}{9 \epsilon }-\frac{236250367 i \epsilon }{479001600}+\log (\epsilon )-\frac{2857}{89600}+\frac{i \pi }{2}+O(\epsilon^1)$

Then you can read the singular part.